# repost xml postback to another url

Tags: php, xml, postback

We are currently using Ultracart for xml postback to a url on our server.  What i'm trying to do is receive that xml, and turn right around and post it to another page. (We were having trouble sending postback to multiple sources for a project we're working on.) Here is what i've been playing with:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('php://input');
$url = 'https://destinationlink';


$post_data = array(
    "xml" => $xml,
);

$stream_options = array(
    'http' => array(
       'method'  => 'POST',
       'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
       'content' => http_build_query($post_data),
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($stream_options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, null, $context);
```

I know i'm missing something vital here...I think i've been looking at it too long and I can't see the problem...probably something stupidly simple.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out CURL was the answer here.

```
//URL where to send the data via POST
$URL1 = 'http://destinationlink';

//the actual data
$xml_data1 = file_get_contents('php://input');


    $ch1 = curl_init($URL1);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data1");
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output1 = curl_exec($ch1);
    curl_close($ch1);
```

That works like a charm.

I can receive the XML postback (php://input), make different blocks with this curl code, based on the destination URLs, and send the information to all of the separate connections I need one by one.